Problem with many connections from RHEL 8.10 to SQL Server
I have simple script:
for i in {1..1000}
do
    isql -v -k "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=mssqlserver,1282;Database=dbname;UID=user;PWD=xxx;Encrypt=no" >> aaa.log &
done

We upgraded OS from RHEL 7.9 to 8.10.
ODBC drivers installed: 11, 13, 17.
Now, when I execute it 99% of the connections are OK, BUT some of them end in error:

SQL> [08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

Such amount of connections are needed in one of SAS programs. 100% of successful connections were in the RHEL 7.9 release.
Can you advice if there is a parameter in Linux, or maybe some ODBC, OPENSSL to have it working again?
I have tried rolling back to RHEL 7.9 and the script is working without any issues.

Please, add your SQL Server version. Also, do you see any errors on SQL Server log? What is your actual ODBC driver version? (Your code says "ODBC Driver 17" but the error says "ODBC Driver 13").

Opening 1000 concurrent connection to any database server is a bad idea; perhaps consider using some sort of connection pooling.

to add info: I have MSSQL server version 16, ODBC drivers installed: 11, 13, 17. When I use ANY of them to connect I get the error message on some of the connections. I believe that some setting, or maybe kernel config changed when upgrade has been performed as on RHEL 7.9 it's working, but on 8.10 it's not

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708033/error-code-0x2746-10054-when-trying-to-connect-to-sql-server-2014-via-odbc-fro

I'm not sure, that this is the same... In my case from e.g 50 connections from loop, only 1-2 fail with the error. Rest will get successful connections.

I'm posting my own solution as an official answer, which helped in my case:

ODBC driver, which was needed for connection was upgraded from 13 to 17

update-crypto-policies   was set to LEGACY

openssl file which was in use (in mine case /etc/pki/tls/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf) updated values:
openssl_conf = default_conf 
[default_conf]  
ssl_conf = ssl_sect  
[ssl_sect]  
system_default = system_default_sect  
[system_default_sect]  
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2  
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1


last but not least /etc/pki/tls/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf having authorization at least 644.


And that's it. After setting all of those values, I have executed isql command (but also sqlcmd) about 10-50k times in a loop, and connection rate was exactly 100%.
Hope this helps someone.
